# $.get data from view Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

My js script

```
jQuery(".unblock").click(function(){
        var num = jQuery('.page.active').text();
        var ban_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

        jQuery.get("http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/user_activity/delete_user_ban", { ban_id : ban_id, num : num }, function(data) {

                jQuery("#ban_list").append(data);

        }, "json");

    });
```

My delete_user_ban function

```
function delete_user_ban()
{
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

    $ban_id = $this->input->post('ban_id');

    $current_page = (int)$this->input->post('num');

    //$this->activity_model->delete_user_ban($ban_id);

    $per_page = 2;

    $data['ban_list'] = $this->user_activity_lib->user_ban_list($user_id, $current_page, $per_page);

    $this->load->view('front_end/ajax_delete_ban', $data);

}
```

and I want to return it here

```
<!--begin ban list-->
<div id="ban_list">
            <?php foreach($ban_list as $value): ?>
      <div class="comment-box small-comment" id="info-ban-1">
          <div class="photo-box">
       <img src="<?=$value['user_image'];?>" alt="" class="photo rounded"/>
       <a href="#" title="" class="corner rounded"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="comment rounded">
       <div class="bg-tl"></div>
       <div class="avatars">
           <a href="#" title=""><?=$value['user'];?></a><span>blocked</span><a href="<?=base_url() . $value['ban_user'];?>" title=""><img src="<?=$value['user_ban_image'];?>" alt=""/><?=$value['ban_user'];?></a>
           <a href="[removed];" title="Unblock" class="unblock" id="<?=$value['ban_id'];?>">unblock</a>
       </div>
          </div>
          <div class="both"></div>
      </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            </div>
      <!--end ban list-->
      <?=$pagination;?>
         </div>
```

What can I say, everything works good EXCEPT data not returned to  .

If I delete this line in function :

```
$this->load->view(‘front_end/ajax_delete_ban’, $data);
```

and add echo ‘1’;

it return where I want ‘1’ but content from here $this->load->view(‘front_end/ajax_delete_ban’, $data); do not return to this div ? Why ?

I have watched response and html what return and here is html lines returning from view (no errors) but do not appear in `JQuery(”#ban_list”).append(data);`

My .get works good but only return one word, also looking response and html in firebug it show returned lines but do not add it to div?

I have made some test :

```
echo '1111';
```

return OK!

```
echo '1111 2222';
```

do not return ?

How to return more then one word and where is my mistake ?

Comment: Why you set the return in `.get` to `json` if you are trying to load html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing get's and post's, no?

Either change your jQuery to `$.post()`

Or change your PHP to `$this->input->get();`

You're also using 'json' in your $.get() call, but returning HTML.

You should json_encode your view.

You can hand a boolean third parameter to `$this->load->view()` that will return the HTML in the view to a string.

```
$myHTML = $this->load->view('front_end/ajax_delete_ban', $data, true);
echo json_encode(array("html" => $myHTML));
```

Then, in your jQuery callback function, you can retreive the html using `data.html`

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to put HTML strings into a `JSON` format. I mean, why not just tell jQuery that we're expecting HTML to be returned?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the harm? It can be very handy for returning additional data back to javascript. Like, for instance, I often json_encode and return `array('success' => true)` or `array('success' => false)` along with the html. That way, I can check response.success and take the proper course of action. Enlighten me of the dangers, I'm genuinely interested, because I do this all the time.

Comment: It's not exactly a big deal. However, I think you should generate the HTML through JavaScript based on the response received from the server (whether it's a success or an error) and then inject the HTML into the document. The point of doing that is to reduce the amount of data transfered between the client and the server. AFAIK, there's no harm. It's just a matter of performance.

Comment: Sometimes you're left with no other choice but to actually provide a way of separation. JSON encoding can do this for you, but straight HTML can't (reliably, or easily). For instance, what if you make an AJAX call and on success you want to append two completely different divs to two completely different parts of the document? It is much easier to use response.div1HTML and response.div2HTML than to parse the single HTML response. And that's what I mean. I used the example of two HTML divs but, often you want to handle additional data back *along* with the actual html 'notification' itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
jQuery("#ban_list").append($('<div></div>').html(data));
```